# Trello card due dates - show day of the week

Tags: trello-cards

Is there a way to show the day of the week for a card's due date?  For example, "Mon Jan 14" instead of just Jan 14?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, it always to the US format (month, day).

Answer (score 1):

While @SteB is right (you can't view due dates in the requested format), I'll just add that if this is a feature request you'd like to make, you can email the developers at feature-ideas@trello.com.

Describe the current as-is state and how you'd like it to behave in the future.